# A topological space $X$ is $T_0$ if and only if each initial source is point separating

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

A source $(f_i: (X,\mathcal{T}) \rightarrow (Y_i,\mathcal{T}_i))_I$ is an initial source if $\mathcal{T}$ is the initial or weak topology with respect to the family of maps $(f_i: X \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{T}_i))_I$. I will abuse notation and write $X$ and $Y_i$ for $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y_i, \mathcal{T}_i)$.
Call a source of maps $(g_{j} : A \rightarrow B_j)_J$ point separating if for all $a \not= \hat{a} \in A$, there exists a $j \in J$ such that $g_{j}(a)\not= g_{j}(\hat{a}).$ 
An external characterization of an initial source $(f_i:X\rightarrow Y_i)_I$ is the following:
Whenever $g: Z \rightarrow X$ is a map. Then $g$ is continuous if and only if for each $i \in I: f_i \circ g$ is continuous.

Show that $X$ is a $T_0$ space if and only if every initial source is point separating.

What I have done: 
'$(\Rightarrow)$" Assume $X$ is $T_0$ and $(f_i: X \rightarrow Y)_I$ initial. Suppose $x \not= y$ in $X$. Then, w.l.o.g., we may assume that there is an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such $y \notin U$. Define a map $g: \underline{2} \rightarrow X$ by g(0) = x and g(1) = y.  (where $\underline{2}$ is the indiscrete topology on $2:= \{0,1\}$.)
If $(f_i)_I$ does not separate $x$ and $y$, then $f_i(x) = f_i(y)$ for each $i \in I$.
Then, it follows that $ f_i\circ g$ is constant for each $i \in I$. Thus it follows that $g$ is continuous. But then $0 \in g^{-1}[U]$ and $1 \notin g^{-1}[U]$ otherwise $y \in U$. On the other hand, since $g^{-1}[U] \not= \emptyset$, we must have $g^{-1}[U] = 2$, since $2$ is indiscrete. A contradiction.

I'm having trouble with the reverse direction. This is what I have tried:
If $X$ is not $T_0$, then there are points $x \not= y$ such that whenever $U$ is open in $X$, we have: $x \in U \Leftrightarrow y \in U$. I have shown that if we assume that every initial source is a point separating and $f_i(x) \not= f_i(y)$ for some $i \in I$ AND $Y_i$ is $T_0$, we obtain a contradiction. But I don't know how to do this if $Y_i$ is not $T_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky thing about the reverse direction is that even if $X$ is not $T_0$, it will still have *some* initial sources that are point-separating (for instance, you could take only one $Y_i$, namely $X$ itself, with the identity map).  So to prove the reverse, you will have to *construct* a particular initial source which is not point-separating from the fact that $X$ is not $T_0$.

Here's one way to do this.  Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ with the topology such that $\{1\}$ is open but $\{0\}$ is not.  Consider the collection of *all* continuous maps $X\to Y$.  Can you show this is an initial source?  And if $X$ is not $T_0$, can you show that it is not point-separating?

(An alternate approach is to take $Y$ to be the quotient of $X$ which identifies $x$ and $y$ together, where $x$ and $y$ are as in your attempt.  You can then show that the quotient map $X\to Y$ is an initial source.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciated.